# Thinkpad T430 boots to read-only after Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

So after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 the system boots to a command-line login. It throws the following errors:

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: 39: /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: cannot create /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available: Read-only file system

usr/lib/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 33: /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: Read-only file system

cat: /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: No such file or directory

run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot exited with return code 1
```

I've tried a couple things that come up when I google this problem such as live-cd booting to use fsck but none of them have worked.

Comment: Can you log in? Do you have a separate `/var` partition? Are there any I/O errors in `dmesg` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try holding down "Shift" will booting to enter the Grub menu. Select the "Advanced" or "Recovery" option. It's usually the second option.

You'll be booted to text-based menu.

Select the option for "Root shell".

Investigate. Check logs.

Try re-mounting the root as read/write:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

If it doesn't work, review the failure reason.

Exit the root shell. You'll be taken back to the text-based menu.

Select the option to resume booting.